Identify check-in/check-out/break-in/break-out using pyzk
I am using pyzk to get attanhere is code
from zk import ZK, const
from datetime import datetime

def get_attendance_records_between_times(start_time_str, end_time_str, zk):
    # Convert string timestamps to datetime objects
    start_time = datetime.strptime(start_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    end_time = datetime.strptime(end_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    # Connect to the device
    conn = zk.connect()
    
    # Enable the device
    conn.enable_device()

    # Get user data
    users = conn.get_users()
    user_map = {user.user_id: user.name for user in users}

    # Get attendance records
    attendances = conn.get_attendance()
    
    # Process attendance records within the given time range
    filtered_attendances = []
    for attendance in attendances:
        attendance_time = attendance.timestamp
        if start_time <= attendance_time <= end_time:
            # Extract relevant information
            user_id = attendance.user_id
            user_name = user_map.get(user_id, "Unknown")
            timestamp = attendance.timestamp
            status_map = {
                0: "Check Out",
                1: "Check In",
                2: "Break Out",
                3: "Break In"
            }
            status = status_map.get(attendance.status, "Unknown")

            # Append a tuple containing the extracted information
            filtered_attendances.append((user_id, user_name, timestamp, status))

    # Disconnect from the device
    conn.disconnect()

    return filtered_attendances

# Initialize the ZK instance
zk = ZK('*********', port=4370, timeout=5, password=0, force_udp=False, ommit_ping=False)

# Get attendance records between specified times
start_time = "2024-05-20 08:00:00"
end_time = "2024-05-20 17:00:00"
attendances_between_times = get_attendance_records_between_times(start_time, end_time, zk)

for user_id, user_name, timestamp, status in attendances_between_times:
    print(f"User ID: {user_id}, User Name: {user_name}, Timestamp: {timestamp}, Status: {status}")




dance of x=zk machine I nowwant to identify is it check in check out...
I am trying to get user checkin checkout... time how I can read touple to get if its checkin check out and some time I get single value in touple.

Use "punch" instead of "status"
            punch_map = {
                0: "Check Out",
                1: "Check In",
                2: "Break Out",
                3: "Break In"
            }
            punch = punch_map.get(attendance.punch, "Unknown")

            # Append a tuple containing the extracted information
            filtered_attendances.append((user_id, user_name, timestamp, punch))

